# Building example device driver error: insmod invalid module format

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

I am following the tutorial @ http://www.embeddedsystemonline.com/home/embedded-system/embedded_linux/lab3-linux-device-driver

on step #7 of this tutorial,

```
$ cd /usr/src/kernels/linux-2.6.20.1/drivers/char/examples
$ /sbin/insmod hello1.ko
```

I then receive the following error (after `sudo /sbin/insmod hello1.ko`)

```
insmod: error inserting 'hello1.ko': -1 Invalid module format
```

Using the lsmod command, I do not see the module in the kernel

Comment: This link explains why invalid module format issues occurs and how to fix it.
Take a look [here.](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x380.html) I see that this is very old thread.
Updating it so that, it will help the people who are recently searching for this particular fix.

Answer (score 4):

Try running the command without doing the `sudo`, instead become root and try it.

```
$ sudo su -
$ /sbin/insmod hello1.ko
```

Also take a look in `dmesg` to see if there are any additional messages as to what went wrong, and also take a peek at the module using `modinfo`.

```
$ modinfo /dir/to/mod/hello1.ko
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by installing headers of correct kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are:

1. using the source code of the same version of kernel, kernel source can be found [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/)
2. using the same kernel Configuration of the current installed kernel, usually can be found here :

   ```
   /proc/config.gz
   /boot/config
   /boot/config-*
   ```
3. using the right compiling toolchain .

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
make clean
```

and then re-run:

```
make
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You may want to add a note _why_ you think this approach will solve the OPs problem, in particular considering that the OP didn't state how the kernel module was built in the first place.